# Calling a button from form2 when clicking a button from form1

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

This is a demo example, I can't use the original code. This context is very simplified.
I want to call a button/event from the child form (form2) when I'm clicking a button from the mother form (form1). I want to do this via subscribing (which I don't really understard since I'm new to coding).

Mother form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.Show();
            //Call the Button from Form2 here
        }


    }
```

Child Form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MessageBox called from Form1 or Form2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Fabio ... well it's good advice ... `f.button1.PerformClick()` with right access modifiers on `button1` will resolve his **EXACT** problem (the one which he wrote in the question) ...

Comment: @Selvin and produce new problems, especially when you or somebody else need to maintain form2 and wonder form1 is breaking.

Comment: @Selvin, yes, you can fix exact problem of Sql syntax error by advising to add missing single quote around injected textbox.Text value or you can suggest to use SqlParameters

Comment: well this is about showing message box not sql and the question is *Calling a button from form2 when clicking a button from form1*

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, the way you want to do it, is in general not a good idea as you should not be relying on UI controls on another from, from your other form.

What you can do to achieve what you asked for without rewriting anything is more like this:

1) in the button click of Form2, you do not do anything else than calling a method on Form2, event handler contains no other logic

2) you make that method of form2 public

3) from your button click on form1, you call that same public method of form2

again, this would work but it is not necessarily the best design, it really depends on the whole architecture of your app if this fits or not with the rest or there are better and different ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call other form "button clicks", if you want to call some logic from different places, extract logic into dedicated class and call it from both places

```
public class MyLogic
{
    public void Execute(string someParameter)
    {
        // Do something with parameter
    }
}
```

Then use it in both forms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly MyLogic _importantLogic;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _importantLogic = new MyLogic();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _importantLogic.Execute(this.textBox1.Text);
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private readonly MyLogic _importantLogic;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _importantLogic = new MyLogic();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _importantLogic.Execute("Always Form 2");
    }
}
```